# Resolving LALR Ambiguities

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, lalr, ambiguous-grammar

I've recently wrapped my head around LALR enough to write an [LALR generator](https://github.com/joshwyant/ParserGenerator), and I'm trying to construct a java- or c#-style grammar for it (the beginnings of which are specified [here](https://github.com/joshwyant/ParserGenerator/blob/master/TestLanguage/Grammar.cs)).

I know it's extra effort to write the parser generator, like re-inventing the wheel (why not use Antlr?), but my goal is to bootstrap a hobby OS that can compile itself without depending on a third-party toolchain. My problem though is not with the generator, but with the grammar.

I'm running into reduce/reduce ambiguities with statements and expressions.

I know how to resolve certain types of ambiguities, such as dangling-else, but these few have are not intuitive to me, and they have me stumped.

What's the best way to resolve these? Also, is there a prototyping tool that I can use to help visualize the solution? Or, should I go back to square one and try implementing a GLR parser generator for the grammar?

These statements are legal:

```
Generic.List<int> myVar1 = x + 4, myVar2; // stmt -> var-decl ;
                                          // var-decl -> type-name var-decl-list

t = 99;                           // simple-stmt -> assign

i++;                              // simple-stmt -> incr-decr
                                  // incr-decr -> primary-expr ++

json.deserialize<list<int>>(obj); // simple-stmt -> call
                                  // call -> primary-expr ( params )
                                  // ...  -> primary-expr . basic-name ( params )
                                  // ...  -> basic-name . basic-name ( params )
```

Here's how it's set up:

```
basic-name : ident < type-list >
           | ident

nested-name : nested-name . basic-name
            | basic-name

basic-type : int | bool | ...

type-name : nested-name
          | basic-type

stmt : var-decl ;
     | simple-stmt ;
     | ...

var-decl : type-name var-decl-list

var-decl-list : var-decl-list , var-init
              | var-init

var-init : ident assign-op expression
         | ident

simple-stmt : assign
            | call
            | incr-decr

expr : assign-expr

assign-expr : assign
            | cond-expr

assign : unary-expr assign-op expr

...
rel-expr : rel-expr < shift-expr
         ...
         | shift-expr

...
unary-expr : unary-op primary-expr
           | primary-expr

unary-op : + - ! ~ ++ --  // Prefix operators
         | ( type-name )  // Conversion operator

primary-expr : call
             | primary-expr . basic-name
             | primary-expr ++
             | ( expr )
             ...
             | basic-name

call : primary-expr ( params )

incr-decr : primary-expr ++
          | -- primary-expr
          | ...
```

So when the parser is expecting a statement, the *LR(k) item set kernel is `method-body -> { * stmts-opt }` and the full item set for the state looks something like this:

```
method-body -> { * stmts-opt }
stmts-opt -> * stmts
stmts-opt -> *
stmts -> * stmts stmt
stmt -> * var-decl ;
stmt -> * simple-stmt ;
var-decl -> * type-name var-decl-list
simple-stmt -> * assign
simple-stmt -> * call
simple-stmt -> * incr-decr
type-name -> * nested-name
type-name -> * basic-type
nested-name -> * nested-name . basic-name
nested-name -> * basic-name
basic-name -> * ident < type-list >
basic-name -> * ident
assign -> * unary-expr assign-op expr
unary-expr -> * unary-op primary-expr
unary-expr -> * primary-expr
unary-op -> * ( typename )
unary-op -> * ! | ~ | ...
primary-expr -> * call
primary-expr -> * primary-expr . basic-name
primary-expr -> * primary-expr ++
primary-expr -> * basic-name
primary-expr -> * ( expr )
call -> * primary-expr ( params )
incr-decr -> * primary-expr ++
...
```

When an identifier is shifted, the next state is:

```
basic-name -> ident *
basic-name -> ident * < type-list >
```

which is parsed out or reduced, and brings the next state to:

```
nested-name -> basic-name *
primary-expr -> basic-name *
```

Potential conflict. In the parent state, lookaheads don't help, since there is a dot in `nested-name` and `primary-expr`. Oh, goody, let's try reducing by nested-name:

```
type-name -> nested-name *
nested-name -> nested-name * . basic-name
```

Nothing to see here...
Now, how about reducing by `primary-expr` instead:

```
unary-expr -> primary-expr *
primary-expr -> primary-expr * . basic-name
primary-expr -> primary-expr * ++
call -> primary-expr * ( params )
incr-decr -> primary-expr * ++
...
```

Now when we shift ++, we get:

```
primary-expr -> primary-expr ++ *
incr-decr -> primary-expr ++ *
```

...another reduce-reduce conflict.

Let's try shifting the `(` instead of the `ident`:

```
primary-expr -> ( * expr )
unary-op -> ( * type-name )
expr -> * assign-expr
assign-expr -> * assign
assign-expr -> * cond-expr
assign -> * unary-expr assign-op expr
unary-expr -> * unary-op primary-expr
unary-expr -> * primary-expr
unary-op -> * ( typename )
unary-op -> * ! | ~ | ...
primary-expr -> * call
primary-expr -> * primary-expr . basic-name
primary-expr -> * primary-expr ++
primary-expr -> * basic-name
primary-expr -> * ( expr )
call -> * primary-expr ( params )
cond-expr -> * ...
...
rel-expr -> * rel-expr < shift-expr
rel-expr -> * shift-expr
...
type-name -> * nested-name
type-name -> * basic-type
nested-name -> * nested-name . basic-name
nested-name -> * basic-name
basic-name -> * ident < type-list >
basic-name -> * ident
```

Same issues when you shift an `ident` or `(` onto the stack.

These are just the ones I've run into so far. Since `basic-name` has precedence over `rel-expr`, I'm assuming something like `x < n` would be interpreted as `basic-name -> ident < type-list *`, and error out if it was actually a relational expression.

My brain has reached the point where I could really use some help.

Comment: Does your LALR-generator implement bison-like precedence declarations? If not, how are we to interpret "Since basic-name has precedence over rel-expr..."?

Comment: @rici Since `rel-expr` derives `basic-name` in so-many steps, I'm saying that it has a higher precedence.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. The fact that A derives B makes no difference in the LR algorithm's decision to shift or reduce.

Comment: @rici Maybe I still don't completely understand. Since there's only once symbol of lookahead, in order to shift the `<` token for a rel-expr we have to reduce the `ident` to `basic-name` then on down to `rel-expr` to get to the state `rel-expr -> rel-expr * < shift-expr`. If we do that though, even if the full input is `x < n > ( )`, we've already reduced to `rel-expr`: `rel-expr * < n > ()`, and we can't get `< type-list >` from the next 3 tokens because in order to do that, we have to get `basic-name -> ident < type-list > *` on the stack, not `basic-name -> rel-expr < type-list > *`.

Comment: That is certainly a shift reduce conflict. It is quite possibly even an ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the current grammar to have a state that inludes the 2 kernel items, `rel-expr -> ident * < shift-expr` and `basic-name -> ident * < type-list >`, because the former is not a real production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86637/discussion-between-josh-wyant-and-rici).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few questions in your post, which makes it not really ideal for SO. But I'll try to provide some thoughts about each one. As I see it, you have three issues:

1. Distinguishing expression statements from expressions which are not statements.
2. Parsing hierarchically-named types in a declaration without conflicting with field-access expressions in expression statements
3. Distinguishing between the use of <kbd><</kbd> as a comparison operator and as a template bracket.

---

#### 1. Distinguishing expression statements from expressions which are not statements.

As I understand, the desire is to only allow as *statements* expressions which have (or potentially have) some kind of side-effect: assignments, increment mutations, and subroutine calls. Roughly speaking, this corresponds to Java, whose grammar includes:

```
StatementExpression:
  Assignment
  PreIncrementExpression
  PreDecrementExpression
  PostIncrementExpression
  PostDecrementExpression
  MethodInvocation
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

Each of the alternatives listed for `StatementExpression` *also* appears somewhere in the derivation tree for `Expression`, where they have been factored out of the lists of possibilities. Here's a very condensed sample:

```
Expression:
  LambdaExpression
  AssignmentExpression

AssignmentExpression:
  ConditionalExpression
  Assignment

Assignment:
  LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator Expression

...

UnaryExpression:
  PreIncrementExpression
  + UnaryExpression
  UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus

PreIncrementExpression:
  ++ UnaryExpression

UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus:
  PostfixExpression
  ~ UnaryExpression

PostfixExpression:
  Primary
  ExpressionName
  PostIncrementExpression

PostIncrementExpress:
  PostfixExpression ++
```

Note how the non-terminals used on the right-hand side of `ExpressionStatement` are special-cased at each precedence level. In the C++ grammar, which doesn't limit which expressions can be statements, there is no need for a separate `Assignment` non-terminal:

```
assignment-expression:
  conditional-expression
  logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
```

But in Java, that won't work. It needs to create the additional non-terminal which does not derive `ConditionalExpression`, precisely in order to allow `Assignment` to be a `Statement` and `AssignmentExpression` to be an `Expression`.

#### 2. Parsing hierarchically-named types in a declaration without conflicting with field-access expressions in expression statements

Similar to the above, here it is necessary to put hierarchical names (which must start with a `basic-name`) from other forms of field access expressions, which might start with any (other) `primary-expr`. The former can be type names or primary expressions; the latter can only be type names. To make this distinction, we need to split the `primary-expr` production:

```
primary-expr : field-access-expr
             | nested-name

non-field-access-expr:
               call
             | post-increment-expression  // was primary-expr ++
             | ( expr )
             ...

field-access-expr :
               non-field-access-expr
             | field-access-expr . basic-name
```

#### 3. Distinguishing between the use of <kbd><</kbd> as a comparison operator and as a template bracket.

Unlike the other two issues, this one might actually be an ambiguity in the language. In C++, for example, template brackets are definitely ambiguous; they can only be resolved by knowing (or being told) whether a particular name is a template name or not. In Java, on the other hand, the ambiguity is solved by sometimes requiring the type parameters to come *before* the generic name. For example:

```
ConstructorDeclarator:
  [TypeParameters] SimpleTypeName ( [FormalParameterList] )
```

or

```
MethodInvocation:
  Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
```

In C#, there is yet a different rule, which requires looking at the character following the <kbd>></kbd> which potentially matches the opening <kbd><</kbd>. The algorithm is described in §7.6.4.2 of the C# manual; I have no idea how you would implement that in an LALR(1) parser.